# How to identify a xfail test from pytest_runtest_makereport hook?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, pytest, hook

### Context

We want to emit test result metric in a near to real-time manner. Therefore, we publish metrics from the `pytest_runtest_makereport` hook. It seems that in the `pytest_runtest_makereport` hook, the tests that **xfailed** or **xpassed** are marked as **skipped**.

### Question

Is there any way that we can identify if a test result is **xfailed** or **xpassed** from `pytest_runtest_makereport` hook?

We could differentiate **xfailed** and **xpassed** test from the **skipped** test from the `pytest_terminal_summary` hook through `terminalreporter` object, which offers a way to get a list of test nodeid by the test result. For example:

```
terminalreporter.stats.get("xfailed", [])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `pytest_runtest_makereport` hook you can use

```
if call.excinfo and call.excinfo.typename == "XFailed":
```

to detect a call to `pytest.xfail("...")` from within the test. If the test was marked with `@pytest.mark.xfail("...")`, you will have to detect the test failure and then look for the mark (or check the mark earlier and remember it).